# How to deep-link a tile with a variable query string?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I created my tile as follows in the hopes that `panelId={0}` could be resolved at runtime, when I send the tile notification to the phone.

```
StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("tile_medium.png", UriKind.Relative),
};

ShellTile.Create(new Uri("MainPage.xaml?Name=MyTile&panelId={0}", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
```

Then I send the following notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
  <wp:Tile Id="/MainPage.xaml?Name=MyTile&amp;panelId=106398738">
    <wp:BackgroundImage>alarm.png</wp:BackgroundImage>
    <wp:Count>72</wp:Count>
    <wp:Title>My Title</wp:Title>
    <wp:BackContent>Text of the tile</wp:BackContent>
  </wp:Tile>
</wp:Notification>
```

I wanted `panelId={0}` to be resolved to `panelId=106398738` but this doesn't seem to happen. Even though the server confirms that the notification was received, the phone never updates the tile.

I've also tried adding `<wp:Param>` to the query string as follows, but this didn't work either:

```
<wp:Param>/MainPage.xaml?Name=MyTile&amp;panelId=106398738"</wp:Param>
```

**Is it possible to deep-link a tile with a variable query string? If so, how?**

Comment: ... almost 18 hours later and no response, I'm surprised that appears so reasonable a request doesn't seem to be possible in Windows Phone! There are some significant limitations to the capabilities of this operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using following snippet:

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    {
        string textValue;
        int value;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("panelId", out textValue))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(textValue, out value))
            {
                // got it!
            }
        }
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```